# MUI DataGrid: How to add custom/specific event listeners such as `rowDragStart` or `rowDragOver`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

MUI DataGrid: How to add custom/specific event listeners such as `rowDragStart` or `rowDragOver`? There are no pre-defined props in DataGrid that supports these listeners.

Here is the official doc: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-ordering/

I tried to pass the callback to onRowOrderChange, but I wasn't succesfull!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was in your shoes before so I had to inquire MUI team specifically, but here you go!

In MUI, to add specific event listeners to DataGrid such as `rowDragStart` or `rowDragOver`, we have to utilize `useGridApiRef`.

1. Declare `const apiRef = useGridApiRef();`
2. Use `apiRef` for `DataGrid`'s `apiRef` property
3. Then, use `apiRef.current.subscribeEvent` method to attach the handler method of your choice

Here is the complete example.

```
// make sure to import GridEventListener, useGridApiRef 
const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

React.useEffect(() => {
  const handleRowDragEnd: GridEventListener<'rowDragEnd'> = (params) => {
    console.log(params)
    // Place your logic here
  };
  // This will manage proper unsubscribe logic to prevent duplicate event handlers
  return apiRef.current.subscribeEvent('rowDragEnd', handleRowDragEnd);
}, [apiRef]);
     
<DataGridPremium
   ...
   rowReordering
   apiRef={apiRef}
   onRowOrderChange={handleRowOrderChange}
/>
```

You could learn more about it [here](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/events/#with-apiref-current-subscribeevent).